# How to make a batch file that resets Wi-Fi Adapter?

Tags: batch-file

my laptop has a faulty Wifi Adapter, and every time I disconnect from the internet (5-10 times a day), I have to click "troubleshoot problems". Windows goes through a whole process to find the problem and then resolves it, but I know the solution is just to reset the Wifi Adapter. So I figured there would be specific commands in cmd for that. I thought I could make a batch file that would run the specific commands in cmd, because that would probably be faster than using the troubleshooting feature. Problem is, I have no idea how to program in batch. May anyone help me?

Answer (score 2):

Had the same issue, tried Junaid's solution, but it didn't work for me.

[This](http://www.neowin.net/forum/topic/1036381-reset-wireless-adapter-automatically/) helped me, however.

TL;DR:

```
netsh interface set interface <interface name> DISABLED

netsh interface set interface <interface name> ENABLED
```

On my machine < interface name> is WiFi, for instance.

Does require admin rights, so it's probably best to make a shortcut to the batch file. I turned it into an executable and pinned a shortcut to it in the taskbar.

Comment: Show interface name:
netsh interface show interface

Answer (score 0):

Start elevated Command Prompt.

```
::Get NIC list and index number:
wmic nic get name, index
```

Now create a `something.bat` file and put these commands

```
::Disable NIC with index number: (eg: 7)
wmic path win32_networkadapter where index=7 call disable
::Enable NIC with index number: (eg: 7)
wmic path win32_networkadapter where index=7 call enable
```

you will need to replace 7 with index number of your interface.

Comment: From time to time I have the same problem with my LAN adapter. This solution didn't work for me, but doing it on the command line worked fine. Maybe there is a timing problem. I put a `timeout 2` between "disable" and "enable" and now wait for the next occurence.

Answer (score -1):

I tried the 4 lines of code and had to make sure the device # in place of the "(eg: 7)" on lines 1 and 3 was typed without the space between the : and the #  (eg, ...index number:7)